# Update column with data from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update one of my tables with data from another table. The tables have the same number of rows if that matters. However when I try to use `UPDATE` and `SET` in the below code, the column Flow in still has all null values.

```
UPDATE #temptableInfo
SET Flow = (SELECT xRFlow
FROM #temptableInfoPre)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sample input?  Table structure?  What's the relationship between the 2 tables?  No one can help you if we don't know these information.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try to use update from-from construction if your tables could by joined on some key fields

```
update #temptable 
set val = B.val
from #temptable A
inner join another_table B on A.id = B.link_to_a_id
```